# Android Kotlin Google Map become Black Screen

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

so i was creating a simple app for android based on a course i take.
The map show just fine before i created a class and function to detect location changed on gps, now whenever the activity opened and permission granted it just show black screen on my phone no error crash or anything but cannot do anything except close the app (i used real device to emulate). 
I already added api key on the xml

this is my code

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    var accessLocation = 123
    var location : Location? = null
    var name : String = "We"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        name = intent.getStringExtra("name")
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        getPermission()
    }

    fun getPermission(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),accessLocation)
                return
            }
        }

        getLocation()


    }

    fun getLocation(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location access permision granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        var myLocationListener = MapListener()
        var locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3,3f,myLocationListener)

        var locationTrack = locationThread()
        locationTrack.start()


    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {

        when(requestCode){
            accessLocation -> {
                if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) getLocation()
                else Toast.makeText(this,"Location access is Needed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }

    inner class MapListener : LocationListener {

        constructor(){
            location = Location("Start")
            location!!.latitude = 0.0
            location!!.longitude = 0.0
        }

        override fun onLocationChanged(position: Location?) {

            location = position
        }

        override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {
//            TODO("not implemented")

        }

        override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String?) {
//            TODO("not implemented")
        }

        override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String?) {
//            TODO("not implemented")
        }


    }

    inner class locationThread : Thread {

        constructor() : super()

        override fun run() {


            while (true){
                try {
                    runOnUiThread{
                    mMap.clear()
                    val located= LatLng(location!!.latitude, location!!.longitude)
                    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                        .position(malang)
                        .title("$name are Here")
                        .snippet("have a nice day")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mario)))
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(located,14f))
                    Thread.sleep(1000)
                    }

                }catch (ex : Exception){

                }
            }

        }


    }


    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap


    }
}
```

This one is manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.furis.sid.pokemon">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

        <activity
                android:name=".MapsActivity"
                android:label="Map">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is what showed up in logcat when the app become black (dont really know which one to show here so i just screenshoot what popped up when it become black)
[logCat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mCJt.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason it was black screen because the onCreate in the activity cant be completed because of the class locationThread , so i added a variable to store old locaation and changed the thread class so that it doesnt always call the function 
every sec when location isnt changed to this :

```
inner class locationThread : Thread {

    constructor() : super(){

        oldLocation = Location("Start")
        oldLocation!!.latitude = 0.0
        oldLocation!!.longitude = 0.0

    }


    override fun run() {


        while (true){
            try {

                if(location!!.distanceTo(oldLocation)==0f) continue
                oldLocation = location

                runOnUiThread{
                mMap.clear()
                val located= LatLng(location!!.latitude, location!!.longitude)
                mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                    .position(malang)
                    .title("$namae are Here")
                    .snippet("Have a nice day")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mario)))
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(located,14f))
                Thread.sleep(1000)
                }

            }catch (ex : Exception){
            }
        }
    }
}
```